How can Google's PageRank AI detection methodology used in its ranking be tested empirically?
I recently had a spirited debate with a good friend who's worked in SEO for about 20 years. They guaranteed me with 100% certainty that Google's PageRank AI detection is able to detect AI generated content with "near 100% accuracy" and it seems like this is a hill they're willing to, proverbially, die on.
I have read from others within the SEO expert space that they have similar opinions, but I've also read that such experts are living in a delusional space presently - without actual data to back up their claims.
While I'm not planning on fighting my friend, or others, further on this topic, I'd like to know how well founded their stances are in fact and data.
I, myself, have had my own personal writings from now and many years ago rank as only 70-90+% "human generated" while I've seen AI generated content, on the same ranking systems, rank AI very similarly. Funny enough I've seen them rank consistently at about the "90+% human" level depending on prompt quality.
Is there any actual method to test Google's and other SEO-impacting bot/calculator methods and ranking?
I'm interested in actual empirical info here that's connected to Google or a search engine company... Not an "AI Detection Expert" company that is not actually in the belly of the SEO calculative beast, so to speak.
